# Hibernate fetch MAP optimization (minimize SELECT statements)

Tags: hibernate, optimization, dictionary, hibernate-mapping

How to fetch a map with no additional select statements.

I have a hbm like this:

> ```
>             <map name="officeSet" table="office_employee" inverse="true" lazy="false"  batch-size="100" cascade="all">
>                 <key column="employee_id"/>
>                 <map-key-many-to-many column="office_id" class="by.epam.hibernatetask.model.Office"/>
>                 <element column="employee_position" type="java.lang.String"/>
>             </map>
> ```

with lazy="false" and fetch="join" I can fetch a SET for 3 hibernate queries but it doesn't work for MAP.
Can't find the solution.

Comment: Try, <set name="officeSet" table="office_employee" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="join">